# Kernel and image of $f:\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}, (a,b)\to 4a-6b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

$f:\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}$,
$(a,b)\to 4a-6b$

For the kernel

$4a-6b=0$

Claim:
$\ker (f)=\{a=\frac{6b}{4},b\in 2\Bbb{Z} \}$

Proof for $\subset$:

Let $(x,y) \in \ker(f)$,
$4x-6y=0$,
$x=\frac{6y}{4} \in \{a=\frac{6b}{4},b\in 2\Bbb{Z} \}$

Proof for $\supset$:

Let $(x,y) \in \{ a=\frac{6b}{4},b\in 2\Bbb{Z} \}$

$4(6y/4)-6y)=0$ thus $(x,y) \in \ker(f)$

For the image:

Claim $\operatorname{Im}(f) = 2\Bbb{Z}$

Proof for $\subset$:
For $(x,y)$, $(4x-6y)=2(2x-3y)$

Let $l\in \Bbb{Z}$
$2\cdot(2\cdot(2l)-3\cdot(l))=2l\in 2\Bbb{Z}$

Proof for $\supset$:

Let $k\in2\Bbb{Z}$
Choose for $x=(k)$, for $y=(k/2)$
thus 
$2\cdot(2\cdot(k)-3\cdot(k/2))=k\in 2\Bbb{Z}$

Please give your feedback. I know this proof isn't very clear and could be a lot better. I have my doubts on the image part as well.

Comment: I'd say that $\ker f=\{(3n,2n):n\in\mathbb Z\}=\left<(3,2)\right>$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see is with the proof of $\mathrm{Im}f\subseteq 2\mathbb Z$. It is in fact sufficient to factor out the $2$, writing
$$f(x,y)=2(2x-3y)\in 2\mathbb Z$$
since $2x-3y\in \mathbb Z$.

This must be proved for arbitrary $x$ and $y$, whereas you made a choice restricting them.

Comment: oh yes thank you :)))

Comment: @asddf No problem.